# Find B given A and impulse response of B/A

Tags: matlab, impulse-response

Here is a small MATLAB function that computes B in B/A given A and the impulse response h of B/A

```
function b = numf(h,a,nb)
%NUMF   Find numerator B given impulse-response h of B/A and denominator A
%   NB is the numerator order. 

nh = max(size(h)); 
impr = filter(1,a,[1 zeros(1,nh-1)]);

egqs = toeplitz(impr,[1 zeros(1,nb)]);

b = h/egqs';
```

Could someone help me understand why these steps give B.

I get what `filter()` and `toeplitz()` do, but not the last line : `b = h/egqs'`

Thanks for any help,

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector `impr` holds the impulse response of length `nh` of an all-pole filter with denominator coefficients given by `a`. Let's call this impulse response $g(n)$. The impulse response $h(n)$ must satisfy the equation

$$h(n)=(g*b)(n)\tag{1}$$

where * denotes convolution. With the given data, this results in an overdetermined system of linear equations, the system matrix of which is the Toeplitz matrix `egqs`. The last line in the code solves this overdetermined system of linear equations corresponding to (1) in a least-squares sense. You could achieve the same using the backslash operator:

```
b = egqs\h';
```